# Card Probability Without Replacement

Tags: probability

So there are 15 cards total, 5 red, 7 orange, and 3 yellow.  At random you pick 3 (no replacement).

What's the probability of picking: 
1) Exactly 2 Red?
2) Not more than one yellow?
3) One of each?

So I understand since it's without replacement, you'd divide the total probability by 15C3, but after that I'm kinda lost...

Comment: 1) exactly 2 red or at least 2 red?

Comment: Sorry, EXACTLY 2 red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have the denominator.  Numerators:

1) Exactly 2 red.

${5\choose 2}{10 \choose 1}$

2) not more than 1 yellow = 0 yellow or 1 yellow

${12\choose 3}+{12 \choose 2}{3\choose 1}$

3) one of each

${5\choose 1}{7\choose 1}{3\choose 1}$

Comment: Hey, if you don't mind, could you explain the second one a little more? Like just how you arrived to that solution?

Comment: @Jetuas Doug gave you ways to select not more than 1 from the 7 orange cards.  You'll need to adjust it to not more than 1 from the 3 yellow cards.

Comment: Ohh, ok that makes sense! Initially I thought you'd have to multiply the numerator by 7/15, to count for the 1 yellow, but this makes much more sense. Thanks!

Comment: @GrahamKemp thanks, moving to fast.

Answer (score 0):

As bellow, so above.

Your denominator $^{15}{\rm C}_{3}$ counts all ways to select $3$ cards from $15$.

So your numerator must count, in a similar fashion, all the ways to so select $3$ cards such that they contain:

> 1) 2 Red?

- Select $2$ from $5$ red *and* $1$ from the $10$ others.

> 2) Not more than one yellow?

- Select $0$ from $3$ yellow and $3$ from $12$ others, *OR* select $1$ from $3$ yellow and $2$ from $12$ others.

> 3) One of each

- Select $1$ from $5$ red, $1$ from $7$ orange, and $1$ from $3$ yellow.